# How to get the last inserted row for each criteria

Tags: mysql, timestamp, max

I need to select the last inserted rows from a database based on several criteria. Below is a sample of the data.

```
TIMESTAMP   CHANNEL LANGUAGE    FORECAST
1   CALL    DUTCH   10
1   EMAIL   DUTCH   20
4   CALL    DUTCH   10
2   EMAIL   DUTCH   20
4   CALL    DUTCH   10
3   CALL    SPANISH 20
3   EMAIL   SPANISH 10
4   CALL    DUTCH   10
```

A timestamp is inserted each time a record is added however, there can be more records with the same timestamp as lots of records can be inserted at the same timestamp.

I need to retrieve all records with the latest timestamp. So, in this example the result should be:

```
TIMESTAMP   CHANNEL LANGUAGE    FORECAST
4   CALL    DUTCH   10
4   CALL    DUTCH   10
4   CALL    DUTCH   10
```

I tried using the max(timestamp) statement but end up with 'earlier' timestamps as well.

This should be easy I think?

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE TIMESTAMP =
(
  SELECT MAX(m.TIMESTAMP) 
  FROM MyTable m
)
```

You don't need an `ORDER BY` in the subquery because it only returns one result anyway.

Comment: Great, that works! And, what if I would like to select all languages but then only the ones with the latest timestamp? So, in the above example: line 3 for Dutch and line 7 for Spanish?

Comment: Sorry, that should be line 3, 5 and 8 for 'dutch' as 4 is the latest timestamp for 'dutch'. For 'spanish' I would need line 7 only (3 is the latest timestamp for 'spanish').

Comment: @Baton If you want to amend your question, amend your question. However, without a PRIMARY KEY, a straightforward solution may prove problematic.